# IN VBA unable to call subroutine in Sheet from Workbook event handlers Workbook_BeforeClose or Workbook_Deactivate()

Tags: vba, events, scope, event-handling, subroutine

I'm making an Excel VBA enabled **Workbook(RES Project Perspective)** has a main table/sheet **(RES Project Sheet)** from which there's a hyperlink on each row to open another **workbook(0520-077-LACOFD-FJF-log.xlsm)** with **Sheet1(Project Log)** which is also VBA enabled.
When **workbook(..log.xlsm**) with **Sheet1(Project Log)** the secondary table is filled out, I want some of those changes to be updated in the main table **(RES Project Sheet)**.

The update subroutine **UpdateMainProjectTable** is in **Sheet1(Project Log)**.  It work when called from Worksheet_changed event, but when I try to call the update subroutine from the workbook events **Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)** or  **Workbook_Deactivate()**, I get the compile error "Sub or Function not defined".
Figuring it is a scope error I also tried naming the subroutine **Sheet1.UpdateMainProjectTable**, but then I get "runtime error 1004  Application Defined or object defined error".

Below are four examples of event handlers used in the Workbook.   I tried each one and they each produced an error when trying to call **UpdateMainProjectTable**.  In the first two exThey are only together for reference.  Also I included a picture of the project structure and the errors for referene.

The two subroutines below are in the Woorkbook, so I prefix Sheet1.  On both when they try to call **Sheet1.UpdateMainProjectTable** I received  "runtime error 1004  Application Defined or object defined error".

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
If Me.Saved = False Then Me.Save
Application.EnableEvents = False
Sheet1.UpdateMainProjectTable
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()
Application.EnableEvents = False
Sheet1.UpdateMainProjectTable
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The two subroutines below are in the Woorkbook, and I don't prefix the subroutine.  On both when they try to call **UpdateMainProjectTable** I received  compile error "Sub or Function not defined".

```
Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()    
 Application.EnableEvents = False
UpdateMainProjectTable
Application.EnableEvents = True    
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
 If Me.Saved = False Then Me.Save
 Application.EnableEvents = False
UpdateMainProjectTable
Application.EnableEvents = True    
End Sub
```

Per the suggestion of an answer I tried this.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
If Me.Saved = False Then Me.Save
Application.EnableEvents = False
With Sheet1
Call UpdateMainProjectTable
End With
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

But I get the **"Compile Error Sub or Funtion not defined"**.
Below is my subroutine inside of Sheet1(Project Log) which is declared **Public**.

```
Public Sub UpdateMainProjectTable()    'This is the Main function to update the main table when the log is updated
                                'it open's the RES Project table if not open and

Dim fileName As String
Dim projId As String
Dim logEntry As String
Dim waitingNotCleared As Boolean
Dim rowWithMatch As Integer
Dim wbOpenOnEntry As Boolean
Dim wb As Workbook

'gets Projectlog filename--  this filename
fileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name

'check if RES Project Perspective.xlsm is open.  If not then open and close later at end of sub
wbOpenOnEntry = CheckIfWBOpen("RES Project Perspective.xlsm")
        If wbOpenOnEntry = False Then
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "/../../RES Project Perspective.xlsm")
        End If

'uses filename to determine projid
projId = ExtractProjectIDFromFilename(fileName)
Debug.Print "projId = ExtractProjectIDFromFilename(fileName)   " & projId
'rowWithMatch = FindRowWithProjIDMatch(projId)
rowWithMatch = GetMatchRowNumber(projId)
Debug.Print "rowWithMatch = GetMatchRowNumber(projId)  " & rowWithMatch
MakeLogEntry (rowWithMatch)

'check if RES Project Perspective.xlsm is open.  If not then open and close later at end of sub
        If wbOpenOnEntry = False Then
            wb.Close savechanges:=True
        End If
End Sub
```

I hope this helps!

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you show the code of UpdateMainProjectTable ?

Comment: @Dorian I updated my question with the code for UpdateMainProjectTable.  In the module Sheet1(Project Log).  It works when called from an event in the Sheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to call a `Sub`/`Function` from a sheet module, **it must not be `Private`** and you must **explicitly** call it.

```
Sheet1.UpdateMainProjectTable
```

If your procedure is not `Private` and exists in `Sheet1`, the problem should be inside the called `Sub` (less probable, I think).

I feel the need to also emphasize that `Sheet1` **is not the sheet name!** It is the sheet module name. I mean, when looking in VBE at your sheet modules you can see something like this: `Sheet1 (Your sheet name)`. If `Sheet1` is the name between parenthesis, it would be wrong... Except the case when both are the same.

**Edited**: I can see (now) your sub. Discussing about `Workbook_Deactivate` event call:

`fileName = ActiveWorkbook.Name` does not make the same sense, because after deactivation, another workbook is active. So, try using `fileName = ThisWorkbook.Name` instead. Do the same for `Workbooks.Open(ActiveWorkbook.Path &  ...`, transforming it in `Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & ...`.

It would be good to also post `CheckIfWBOpen` function code, or at least, check if something similar does not exist inside its code.

`ExtractProjectIDFromFilename` is called using a wrong workbook name (the active workbook one). I do not know what other references may also exist in its code.

Since there are also some other functions calls (`GetMatchRowNumber`, `MakeLogEntry`) these procedures must be also analyzed from similar points of view.

Now, I would suggest you to try debugging the call in this event in the next way:

1. Change `ActiveWorkbook` with `ThisWorkbook` as suggested;
2. Put a break Point on the specific line and then press F8 to run the code line by line, when code stops after deactivation and see at which line it raises the error...

Comment: @Frank: It looks that we reached my answer phrase: "If your procedure is not `Private` and exists in `Sheet1`, the problem should be inside the called `Sub`". Now, I can see you posted the `Sub` in discussion. I will edit my answer and make some references to the above mentioned code.

Comment: @Frank: Glad to here you solve it. It may happen in VBA to receive the error much before the line where it is raised. Usually, such things often happens when you call a sub form from another application (for instance a sub in Corel VBA form, from Excel) all the time the error is shown on the called sub, even if it calls another one and the error happens in the third called one. That's why I suggested that the problem may be in the called procedure. I am glad I could be helpful in solving of your problem. But I still do not understand why you do not comment on my answer...

Comment: @Frank:  That answer may be deleted and all our comments will disappear, somebody else interested in learning something from the question history will not understand too much... Did you find the error place stepping line by line?

Answer (score 1):

**Be sure** that your sub is **`Public`** :

```
Public Sub UpdateMainProjectTable()

End Sub
```

And to `Call` this sub just do :

```
With Sheet1
    Call UpdateMainProjectTable
End With
```

So your code should be as follow :

```
Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()    
Application.EnableEvents = False
With Sheet1
    Call UpdateMainProjectTable
End With
Application.EnableEvents = True    
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
If Me.Saved = False Then Me.Save
Application.EnableEvents = False
With Sheet1
    Call UpdateMainProjectTable
End With
Application.EnableEvents = True    
End Sub
```

Comment: It is not necessary to be `Public`. It is necessary **to not be `Private`**. And,also, a procedure in a sheet module can be called **only explicitly, using the sheet module name when call it**...

Comment: @FaneDuru Its declared public and i tried calling it by using the statement "Sheet1.UpdateMainProjectTable".  I received "runtime error 1004 Application Defined or object defined error" .

Comment: @Frank: Did you read my answer? All of it... If yes, it would be good to comment on my answer. No need to tag me... What 'Sheet1` is, in fact? The sheet name or the sheet module name? Do you distinguish between the two concepts? Receiving of that error is normal, since the call is out of sheet module scope.

Comment: @Dorian  I tried your suggestion, but get a "Compile Error Sub or Function not defined".

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes I read it.  An think I understood.  The sub is explicitly Public.  And I tried it by prefixing the sub with "Sheet1." the module name for the (Project Log) sheet.   I added the code for UpdateMainProjectTable sub to my question.  I hope that helps.

Comment: @Frank:  Did you also pay attention to the `Sheet1` meaning?

Comment: @FaneDuru I think I understood what you mean.  The module is Sheet1(Project Log), so I referred to it as Sheet1.UpdateMainProjectTable  when I tried to call the sub routine.  Am I understanding you correctly??

Comment: @Frank: Yes, you are. So, you use the sheet module name and you still receive that type of error? If yes, try, please create a testing sub in a standard module and try calling the procedure with exactly the same code. Does it work as expected?

Comment: @Frank: Also, create, please a new test sub wherever you want containing the next line: `Debug.Print Worksheets("Project Log").codeName`. What does it return in Imediate Window?

Comment: @FaneDuru  OK.  Debug.Print Worksheets("Project Log").codeName  returns the codeName "Sheet1".     Standy for results from the other tests..

Comment: @FaneDuru I've put test subs in the Sheet1 and in a new Module like you said.  I can run the test subs on the sheet *from* the Workbook events with Sheet1.testSub and in the module by just calling testSub.  I also found that I can run Sheet1.UpdateMainProjectTable from the Workbook, but not in Workbook_Deactivate() or Workbook_BeforeClose() event.  It will run from those workbook events if I place it in the module and call it by simply UpdateMainProjectTable.

Comment: @Frank: Of course, you can try making a new sub (in ThisWorkbook), which to be called by these events, but I am afraid that you would receive a similar message. But, do that and see in which sub the error will appear...

Comment: @FaneDuru OK.  I found what was causing the run-time error 1004. "Sheet1.UpdateMainProjectTable" calls  sub "MakeLogEntry" , and in MakeLogEntry there was a spelling error in a named column reference. When I corrected the spelling it worked.   But what I don't understand is there error propagated up from the miss-named column up to subs to when I call Sheet1.UpdateMainProjectTable. What's also odd is that after correcting the column name in MakeLogEntry I accidentally commented out a "IF" and left the "END IF" , VBA caught it at runtime but reported it at the exact spot where I made the error.

Comment: @Frank you must have a look [on vba error handling](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/) It is usefull. Full free to accept an answer if your issue is solved !